# I am not able to connect to my ec2 server using ssh in circle ci

Tags: circleci

I have added the private key to circle ci and added following in .circleci/config.yml

```
tar -zcvf test.tar.gz src/
scp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" test.tar.gz myproject@2.75.83.192:/home/myproject/
ssh myproject@52.75.83.192 tar -xvzf test.tar.gz
```

After giving permission to  port 22 for ip address, I am able to execute these commands. But when disabling the port, the following error is occurs.

```
src/
src/demo.php
ssh: connect to host 52.75.83.192 port 22: Connection timed out

lost connection
ssh: connect to host 52.75.83.192 port 22: Connection timed out

Exited with code 255
```

How can I enable the port only for the circle ci?

Comment: Your title question doesn't match the question you ask at the end. Your actual question is "How can I enable the port only for the CircleCI?"

Answer (score 0):

You can't. I'd just enable the port, make sure you're using a strong SSH keypair and have taken other security measures on the instance.

Typically, you can limit a port to specific IPs and that would be the way to go here. Problem is, a service like CircleCI runs in AWS, and not from any specific IP or even region. There source IP can and likely will change often. There would be no good way to limit to just CircleCI without having to constantly update your EC2s firewall.